# How can Karger's algorithm (and other randomized algorithms) be used in practice?

Tags: probability-theory, randomized-algorithms

Suppose I am given the following problem (the source is [here](https://www.careercup.com/question?id=5104398418051072)):

> Disconnect two nodes in a graph by removing minimum number of edges.

I would apply Karger's min-cut algorithm. But how can I guarantee that I'll finally find the min-cut? Karger's algorithm is a *randomized* algorithm. If the probability of success is *1/p*, I could run it *p* times to get the answer, right? Not necessarily! What if I am extremely unlucky, so I will never (or too much time will pass) get the answer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Karger's algorithm is a randomized algorithm.  It has a small probability of error, but that probability can be made arbitrarily (exponentially) small simply by repeating the approach.

If we do one round of the algorithm, it has a probability of success of $p$.  If you repeat it $100/p$ times and take the best cut found in any of those iterations, then the probability of success is incredibly high: the algorithm fails only if all $100/p$ iterations fail, so the probability of failure is

$$(1-p)^{100/p} \approx e^{-100} < 2^{-128},$$

and the probability of success is larger than $1 - 2^{-128}$.  For Karger's algorithm, $p=1/{n \choose 2}$, so we repeat it $100 {n \choose 2}$ times, and we obtain a probability of success that is larger than $1 - 2^{-128}$.

For all engineering purposes this is equivalent to a guarantee of success.  For instance, the probability that a cosmic ray hits your computer and causes a bitflip error that causes the algorithm to produce the wrong result is far higher than $2^{-128}$, but we're apparently willing to accept that -- so we should be glad to accept Karger's algorithm too, as long as we repeat it enough times.

See the Wikipedia article for more explanation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karger%27s_algorithm

Comment: Please fix the markdown here: 1 - 2^{-128}$

Comment: @D.W. But a suggested edit has to be at least six characters. :-(